# Why does the KeyDown Event Not Work?

Tags: c#

Below is my entire code, there are no other forms, classes etc that might interfere with the code. I just wrote this quickly for testing. Note that I know I have

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

twice, that's because I saw it in both places when looking up example code. Code compiles with no errors. I've also tried this code using textBox, with the same non-working result.

The `e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter` is the code that does not work. I also tried other keys, such as W and A. Does anyone know what else I need to do? Using VS2010.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("True");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It can work without KeyPreview also if everything is correct!

Comment: Have you put a debugger stop in the Form1_KeyDown method to see if the code is actually executing?

Comment: KeyPreview is a VB6 property and behaves like it did back in the VB6 days.  Which was weirdo, it doesn't fire the event for navigation keys.  Like Enter.  Just don't use it and pick the proper .NET way, override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `IsInputKey` property to true.

[Control.KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This code is what worked, thank you!

 protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("True");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You never subscribed the `KeyDown` event. Check the following [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) snippet:

```
public void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new MyForm());
}

public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        this.KeyDown += this.OnKeyDown;
    }

    public void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Dump();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `ProcessCmdKey` method as below:

```
   protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //write your code here
            MessageBox.Show("Enter");
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```